# How to run job initialization on different nodes one by one?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a multi-node Kubernetes cluster built with microk8s under Ubuntu 22.04. On the cluster, I need to run a `job` (YAML fragment below), which requires pulling a docker image (during initialization) by each node. This concentrated image pull seems to have created a network issue, and cause my network connection to break down.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  template:
    spec:      
      containers:
      - name: myjob
        image: some_docker_image
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

...

Hence the question.

*Is there a way to make Kubernetes pull the docker image one node at a time?*

That is, if there are ten nodes in the cluster, the first node pulls the docker image, and then the second node pulls (only after the first node finishes pulling), and then the third node pulls etc..